# Docker: Error finding main file to run my python backend in docker-compose command

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to run my database and a python backend inside a docker container. I successfully build my container but the docker-compose up can't find my main file to initialize the backend.

My folder organization:

```
|-app
|  |-facadeadd
|  |  |-bd
|  |  |  |-Dockerfile
|  |  |...
|-Dockerfile
|-main.py
|-docker-compose.yml
|-requirements.txt
```

My Dockerfile content backend:

```
FROM python:3.8


RUN apt-get update -y; apt-get upgrade -y
RUN yes | apt install build-essential portaudio19-dev
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt ./dependecies/
COPY . /usr/src/app/

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install torch
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

My Dockerfile content bd:

```
FROM mysql:latest

COPY ./Titulos.xlsx ./bd/
```

My docker-compose.yml conten

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  
  python_app:
    build: ./
    container_name: python-backend
    volumes:
      - ./app:/usr/src/app
    command: sh -c "sleep 10s ; python3 ./main.py"
    depends_on:
      - mysql_db

  mysql_db:
    build: ./facadeadd/bd/
    container_name: mysql-bd
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./bd/:/var/lib/mysql-bd/
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'bd'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
    ports:
      - '3300:3300'
```

And the command log:

```
docker-compose up
[+] Running 2/2
 - Container 3f788211e96a_3f788211e96a_mysql-bd  Recreated                                                                                                                                             0.2s 
 - Container python-backend                      Recreated                                                                                                                                             0.2s
Attaching to mysql-bd, python-backend
mysql-bd        | 2022-11-28 12:40:25+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.31-1.el8 started.
mysql-bd        | 2022-11-28 12:40:25+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
mysql-bd        | 2022-11-28 12:40:25+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.31-1.el8 started.
mysql-bd        | '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
mysql-bd        | 2022-11-28T12:40:26.218689Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
mysql-bd        | 2022-11-28T12:40:26.219609Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.31) starting as process 1
mysql-bd        | 2022-11-28T12:40:26.238489Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
mysql-bd        | 2022-11-28T12:40:26.586560Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
mysql-bd        | 2022-11-28T12:40:26.777184Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting XA crash recovery...
mysql-bd        | 2022-11-28T12:40:26.781021Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] XA crash recovery finished.
mysql-bd        | 2022-11-28T12:40:26.919213Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
mysql-bd        | 2022-11-28T12:40:26.919255Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
mysql-bd        | 2022-11-28T12:40:26.924477Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
mysql-bd        | 2022-11-28T12:40:26.950417Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
mysql-bd        | 2022-11-28T12:40:26.950527Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.31'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
python-backend  | python3: can't open file './main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
python-backend exited with code 2
```

Comment: Did you try to hook up a console and check where the `main.py` actually is?

Comment: How do i do that??

Comment: `docker-compose exec python_app sh`

Comment: that´s the response ```service "python-backend" is not running container #1```

Comment: You can also `docker-compose run python_app sh` to get a debugging shell, not attached to an existing running container.

Comment: The `volumes:` seem potentially problematic, since they overwrite the image's code with other content (and the paths seem like they may not match up); does deleting that block help?  You also shouldn't need a Compose `command:` override to replace the image's `CMD`.

Comment: I restarted all my images and deleted the volumes in docker-compose file. Still getting the same error of finding the main.py